# merging arrays using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this set of an array of objects:

```js
let x = [{
    CategoryName: 'abc',
    Items: ['3A']
  },
  {
    CategoryName: 'xyz',
    Items: ['5Z']
  },
  {
    CategoryName: 'abc',
    Items: ['6B']
  },
  {
    CategoryName: 'abc',
    Items: ['9C']
  },
  {
    CategoryName: 'xyz',
    Items: ['1X']
  }
];
```

what I want is:

```
[
    {CategoryName:'abc',Items['3A','6B','9C']},
    {CategoryName:'xyz',Items['1X','5Z']}
]
```

How I can I achieve this using `lodash`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What did you try which did not work?

Comment: Thanks, I tried merging them using forEach, but it didnt worked out for me. It became so complicated and complexity was very high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `group` it by **CategoryName** and `flatMap` that result by `Items`. That's it!

```
_(x).groupBy('CategoryName').map((v, k)=> ({CategoryName: k, Items: _.flatMap(v, 'Items')})).value()
```

Working demo:

```js
let x = [{"CategoryName":"abc","Items":["3A"]},{"CategoryName":"xyz","Items":["5Z"]},{"CategoryName":"abc","Items":["6B"]},{"CategoryName":"abc","Items":["9C"]},{"CategoryName":"xyz","Items":["1X"]}],
    res;
    
res = _(x).groupBy('CategoryName').map((v, k)=> ({CategoryName: k, Items: _.flatMap(v, 'Items')})).value();

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am getting _.flatmap is not a function

Comment: Its `_.flatMap` *M* is capital. By the way which version of lodash you are using?

Comment: Lodash 4, yes I had written ```_.flatMap``` only

Answer (score 0):

With lodash you could do this also with [`_.groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy) and [`mergeWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mergeWith):

```js
let data = [{ CategoryName: 'abc', Items: ['3A'] }, { CategoryName: 'xyz', Items: ['5Z'] }, { CategoryName: 'abc', Items: ['6B'] }, { CategoryName: 'abc', Items: ['9C'] }, { CategoryName: 'xyz', Items: ['1X'] } ];

const result = _.map(_.groupBy(data, 'CategoryName'), x => 
  _.mergeWith(...x, (o,s) => _.isArray(s) ? o.concat(s) : o))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Or with [`_.transform`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#transform):

```js
let data = [{ CategoryName: 'abc', Items: ['3A'] }, { CategoryName: 'xyz', Items: ['5Z'] }, { CategoryName: 'abc', Items: ['6B'] }, { CategoryName: 'abc', Items: ['9C'] }, { CategoryName: 'xyz', Items: ['1X'] } ];

const result = _.transform(data, (r, {CategoryName, Items}) => {
  r[CategoryName] = r[CategoryName] || ({CategoryName})
  r[CategoryName].Items = [...Items, ...r[CategoryName].Items || []]
}, {}) 

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Or simply with just **ES6** and `Array.reduce`:

```js
let data = [{ CategoryName: 'abc', Items: ['3A'] }, { CategoryName: 'xyz', Items: ['5Z'] }, { CategoryName: 'abc', Items: ['6B'] }, { CategoryName: 'abc', Items: ['9C'] }, { CategoryName: 'xyz', Items: ['1X'] } ];

const result = data.reduce((r,{CategoryName, Items}) => {
  r[CategoryName] = r[CategoryName] || ({CategoryName})
  r[CategoryName].Items = [...Items, ...r[CategoryName].Items || []]
  return r
}, {}) 

console.log(Object.values(result))
```